# How to searching in SQL database using WinForm datetimepicker C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datetimepicker

I created a model that connects SQLserver 2014 and VisalStudio2013(.NET 4,5) , Visal C# .In VB I have two forms аnd in SQL one table with records.

In fist Winform I used "textbox" wich type is *nvarchar*(10) for searching in SQL database.

**But in the second Winform I want to  searching in SQL database using "datetimepicker" where the type of colum is *date* **

What must change in my code for this seach.Becouse give me
 : Error    7   Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime?' and 'int

If must white new code ,what should be ?

This is the code from first form for searching

```
        textKkKod1.Focus();

        loadSearchData();

        int kochani;
        try
        {
            kochani = Convert.ToInt32(this.textKkKod1.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error 404");
            return;
        }
        string kodNaKonduktor = this.textKkKod1.Text;
        var koch = db.Koches.Where(k => k.CODEK == kochani).FirstOrDefault();

        if (koch == null)
            return;

        this.textKkKod1.Text = Convert.ToString(koch.CODEK);
        //this.textKkKochaniData1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(koch.DATER);
        this.textKkRazpiska1.Text = koch.Razpiska;



    }

    private void loadSearchData()
    {



        int kochani;
        try
        {
            kochani = Convert.ToInt32(this.textKkKod1.Text);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Eror 404");
            return;
        }
        kochBindingSource.DataSource = db.Koches.Where(k => k.CODEK == kochani).ToList();

        this.gridKochaniKonduktor1.DataSource = this.kochBindingSource.DataSource;


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The error you are getting is saying that you are trying to compare a date to an integer. You cannot compare two objects of different types.

From the code in your question, this is caused by line:

```
var koch = db.Koches.Where(k => k.CODEK == kochani).FirstOrDefault();
```

The same error would also appear here:

```
kochBindingSource.DataSource = db.Koches.Where(k => k.CODEK == kochani).ToList();
```

We know `kochani` is an integer, which means `CODEK` must be a datetime. (Unless I've missed it, you haven't shown us how `CODEK` is declared/ initialized/ assigned too.)

You need to either convert `CODEK` to an `integer`: (I doubt you'll be able to store a date as an integer actually, best to use `long`)

```
long codekAsLong = long.Parse(CODEK.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
```

Or convert `kochani` to a `datetime` to fix this.

```
DateTime kochaniAsDT = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(kochani);
//This assumes kochani represents milliseconds
```

-I cannot tell you which as I don't know the context in which this code is being used. (I'm struggling with the variable names enough as it is...)